# How to render large web pages

Tags: web, reactjs, html

I have a web application that allow users to search for some products, but in some cases the returned data from server more than 1000 row, which will results in browser hanging and more time to be fully loaded.

my question is how to render the returned data without hanging in client side and less loading time.

I am not familiar with ReactJS, but if make the render to be on the server and on user request the data will be provided to him, is this way helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized in the past with some success. The trick is to only load some data at a time, plus it already handles only rendering the rows that are visible. I've also tried doing it without these optimizations and you end up waiting multiple seconds for the data to render; sometimes long enough for the browser to prompt the user to cancel the script from running. The only render what's in view method is the better experience by far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Lazy Loading with reactJS](http://w33ble.github.io/understanding-react/demos/lazy-load.html) to display the results as the user scrolls down and not load all the data at once in the result page, you can take a look at [Wikipedia difination with examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) or take a look at [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456846(v=vs.100).aspx)
to learn more.